# Failing to create Azure Databricks cluster because of unreachable instances

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-databricks

I'm trying to create a cluster in Azure Databricks and getting a such error messgae

```
Resources were not reachable via SSH. If the problem persists, this usually indicates a network environment misconfiguration. Please check your cloud provider configuration, and make sure that Databricks control plane can reach Spark clusters instances.
```

I have such the default configuration:

Cluster mode: `Standard`

Pool: `None`

Runtime version: `5.5 LTS`

Autoscaling enabled

Worker Type: `Standard_DS3_v2`

Driver Type: `Standard_DS3_v2`

From Logs Analytics I see Azure tried to create virtual machines and without any reason (I suppose because they were unreachable) had to delete all of them.

Did anyone face such issue?

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is temporary, this may be caused by the driver of the virtual machine going down or a networking issue since Azure Databricks was able to launch the cluster, but lost the connection to the instance hosting the Spark driver referring to [this](https://kb.azuredatabricks.net/clusters/termination-reasons.html#communication-lost). You could try to remove it and create the cluster again.

If the problem persists, this may happen when you have an [Azure Databricks workspace deployed to your own VNet](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject.html). If the virtual network where the workspace is deployed is already peered or has an ExpressRoute connection to on-premises resources, the virtual network cannot make an `ssh` connection to the cluster node when Azure Databricks is attempting to create a cluster. You could add a user-defined route (UDR) to give the Azure Databricks control plane `ssh` access to the cluster instances.

For detailed UDR instructions, see [Step 3: Create user-defined routes and associate them with your Azure Databricks virtual network subnets](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/on-prem-network.html#create-routes). For more VNet-related troubleshooting information, see [Troubleshooting](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject.html#troubleshooting)

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Just to comment: one can  have an opposite issue adding routing table/route intended for peered/Express Route networks to a Databircks subnets which are non peered/non express route by mistake - that will lead to the same error.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** Instances Unreachable: Resources were not reachable via SSH.

**Possible cause:** traffic from control plane to workers is blocked. If you are deploying to an existing virtual network connected to your on-premises network, review your setup using the information supplied in [Connect your Azure Databricks Workspace to your On-Premises Network](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/on-prem-network.html#on-prem-network).

Reference: [Azure Databricks - Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/vnet-injection#troubleshooting)

Hope this helps.

Comment: there is an absolutely the same instance of databricks with the same configuration (I compared exported JSON configs), and it works..

Comment: Hi @deeptowncitizen, Would you like you post that as an answer so you can mark this question as answered?